# How to remove delivery shipping step on Prestashop 1.7

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

I want to remove delivery shipping step from Prestashop 1.7, so the user will redirect to payment directly , I already removed address step , but I can't to do the same thing for the delivery shipping step

can you please suggest me a solution ?

Thank you

Comment: Hi. Join Prestashop Group on Facebook and also ask here https://www.facebook.com/prestashark.eu/ Stack is not good place to solve this kind of problems. I recommend to create "Virtual product" instead of normal. Then shipping options will be hidden for this order. Cheers! :)

Answer (score -1):

I recommend using virtual articles instead of hiding the address section. As soon as there are only virtual products in the card, Prestashop is only asking for an invoice address, not for a shipping address. Please note that a valid invoice address is legaly required and mandatory in many countries.